# Fix React-script version vulnerability result in webpack dependency error

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-scripts

A while ago, I have encountered a npm vulnerability called "`Missing Origin Validation`".

The message was following:

```
  High            Missing Origin Validation

  Package         webpack-dev-server

  Dependency of   react-scripts

  Path            react-scripts > webpack-dev-server

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/725
```

When I follow NPM's instruction and fixed it by run npm install `react-scripts@2.1.1`. It was fine.

Recently, on my other branch(Lets call it branch `test`) I installed webpack for some purpose. Even though the webpack was technically only installed in my `test` branch, when I switch to my `master` branch, this happened:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.19.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\pzheng\my-app\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.25.1)
```

I dont see webpack installed in my master branch's package.json. However,  I still followed the NPM's instruction: deleted my `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` then I ran `npm install`

It fixed,but then the `Missing Origin Validation` vulnerability appears again. I am running into a cycle at this point. In the future the `test` branch will be merged. Then I need to pick a version. However, either version will cause an error.

Any help is appreciated.